# Return IDENT_CURRENT which was inserted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have `INSERT INTO SqlCommand` and I need to display after INSERT INTO the `IDENT_CURRENT` which was inserted with these values

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO kliplat (datum,text,castka,akce,subkey,priznak,rocnik) values (@datum,@text,@castka,@akce,@subkey,@priznak,@rocnik)", spojeni);
         spojeni.Open();

         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subkey", vyber_id_kli);
         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@akce", vyberakce);
         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priznak", vyberplat);
         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", maskedTextBox1.Text);
         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", textBox1.Text);
         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@castka", textBox2.Text);
         sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rocnik", rocnik);

         sc.ExecuteReader();
         spojeni.Close();
```

This IDENT_CURRENT is: `INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY`

Now I was dealing with this issue like this:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('mytable')", conn);
                 spojeni.Open();
                 int max = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());

                 spojeni.Close();
```

But I found out that this is extremely hazardous to do.

Thank you all for your time reading this.

Comment: @KingKing Sorry for my brief question. I need to return value IDENT_CURRENT which was inserted with this INSERT INTO SqlCommand

Comment: Use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); and execute it together with the Insert in one batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a command that returns the newly inserted id:

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"
    INSERT INTO kliplat (datum,text,castka,akce,subkey,priznak,rocnik) 
    VALUES (@datum,@text,@castka,@akce,@subkey,@priznak,@rocnik);
    SELECT scope_identity();
    ", spojeni);
...
var newIdentity = (long) sc.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask how can I access this `newIdentity` result from another methods? I created `public int newIdentity` but it returns `0` . Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may consider using [scope_identity()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function instead of ident_current.

> SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT, and @@IDENTITY are similar functions
>   because they return values that are inserted into identity columns.
>   IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a
>   specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the value generated for a
>   specific table in any session and any scope. For more information, see
>   IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL). SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the
>   last identity values that are generated in any table in the current
>   session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within
>   the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your field is called `ID`; add this to your query:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
```

And catch the result in your c# code

Comment: What is `INSERTED`? If it is a keyword, it's strange that I've never heard of this before, sounds interesting.

Comment: Not sure what it technically is but it is like a row that contains all fields that were inserted by the statement. Documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx